# Let $X=\mathbb{D}^2/\sim$, where $(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))\sim(\cos(\theta+\frac{2\pi}{3}),\sin(\theta+\frac{2\pi}{3}))$, $\theta\in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

Let $X=\mathbb{D}^2/\sim$, where $(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))\sim(\cos(\theta+\frac{2\pi}{3}),\sin(\theta+\frac{2\pi}{3}))$ for all $\theta\in \mathbb{R}$. How is this topological space graphically? What does it look like? Thank you.

Comment: Unlike $\mathbb R\mathbb P^2$ (the case $n=2$ for which your construction is $n=3$) the surface is not a smooth manifold as there is an excess angle at the third roots of unity, which are identified to a single point that is a cone point singularity. It is an orbifold obtained as a quotient of a suitable surface under $3$-fold symmetry.

Comment: The failure to be a manifold is more to do with having too many manifold "branches" meeting at some points and so it's not even locally Euclidean. In my answer I point out that (assuming the given equivalence relation only applies to the boundary and so we get a dunce cap) this space can be made by attaching a disk to a circle with a map of degree 3 on the boundary, so in the quotient space all the points in that circle see three different branches.

Comment: @pre-kidney 
What happens if instead of having $\mathbb{D}^2$, we have $S^1$, that is, if the space is $X=S^1/\sim$ where $(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))\sim (\cos(\theta+\frac{2\pi}{3}),\sin(\theta+\frac{2\pi}{3}))$, in this case we could determine which space is homotopically equivalent $X$? Thank you.

Comment: @pre-kidney 
I could calculate the homology groups of this space by calling $A=\text{
the points that are identified in this space}$ and using $...\to H_n(A)\to H_n(X)\to H(X,A)\to H_{n-1}(A)\to...$ is it 
exact?

Comment: @William I could calculate the homology groups of this space by calling $A=\text{
the points that are identified in this space}$ and using $...\to H_n(A)\to H_n(X)\to H(X,A)\to H_{n-1}(A)\to...$ is it 
exact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that your equivalence relation is only defined for points on the boundary circle, so only those points are being identified. On the boundary $\partial D^2$, the equivalence class of a point $x = (cos \theta, sin \theta)$ is 
$$ [x] = \{\ (cos \theta, sin \theta),\  (cos (\theta + \frac{2\pi}{3}), sin (\theta + \frac{2\pi}{3}) ),\ (cos (\theta + \frac{4\pi}{3}), sin (\theta + \frac{4\pi}{3}) )\ \}$$

(This can be expressed more compactly by treating $x\in \partial D^2$ as a complex number: if we let $\xi$ be a primitive 3-rd root of unity then $[x] = \{ x, \xi x, \xi^2  x \}$. ) So on the boundary the quotient map takes the form $S^1 \to S$ where 
$$ S = \{ (cos \theta, sin \theta)\ |\ 0\leq \theta \leq \frac{2\pi}{3} \}/\left((1,0) \sim (cos\frac{2\pi}{3}, sin\frac{2\pi}{3})\right) $$
Then $S$ is homeomorphic to $S^1$ and the quotient map on the boundary has degree $3$.

In fact our quotient space $X = D^2/\sim$ is homeomorphic to the space obtained by attaching a disk $D^2$ to a circle $S^1$ via a map of the boundary $\partial D^2 \to S^1$ of degree 3 (exercise). This is called the "3-fold dunce cap" (at least that's what Munkres calls it in his algebraic topology book) and the construction generalizes to arbitrary $n\geq 1$. If you're familiar with polygonal representations of surfaces, you can express the $n$-fold dunce cap with an $n$-gon whose edges are all identified with the same orientation.  These are not embeddable in $\mathbb{R}^3$ unless $n=1$ (and as @pre-kidney points out in the comments we get $\mathbb{RP}^2$ if $n=2$) so it's not necessarily easy to visualize.

(Note: there is a Wikipedia article about a [dunce hat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunce_hat_(topology)) which is actually something slightly different, and the colliding nomenclature is extremely unfortunate.)

---

**Edit:** There was a discussion in the comments about how to compute the homology of this space, so I decided to include it in my answer for posterity (even though it's not technically part of the question). I will use the notation $q\colon D^2 \to X$ for the quotient map and $[x]$ the equivalence class of a single point, and I will stick to complex coordinates because they are more compact.

We can compute the cellular homology directly, given the description as a $2$-dimensional complex constructed by attaching $D^2$ to $S^1$ by a degree $3$ map on the boundary. If cellular homology is not available we can use Mayer-Vietoris instead.

Let $U = X \setminus [0]$ and $V = q(int D^2)$. Then $U$ and $V$ are open, $U\cup V = X$, and $U\cap V$ is homeomorphic to an open annulus and hence homotopy equivalent to $S^1$. Moreover $V$ is contractible and $U$ deformation retracts onto $S = q(\partial D^2)$, which is homeomorphic to $S^1$ as above. Then the interesting segment of the Mayer-Vietoris sequence is

$$\dots H_2(X) \to H_1(U\cap V) \to H_1(U) \oplus H_1(V) \to H_1(X) \to H_0(U\cap V) \to \dots $$
All of the groups to the left of this segment vanish, and the map $H_1(X) \to H_0(U \cap V)$ is $0$, so the sequence reduces to

$$ 0 \to H_2(X) \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \to H_1(X) \to 0$$

and all that remains is to compute the homomorphism $H_1(U\cap V) \to H_1(U)$ induced by inclusion. We take it as given that if $Y\cong S^1$ then a generator of $H_1(Y)$ can be represented by any loop $\gamma \colon [0,1] \to Y$ that goes one time around. It follows then that a generator of $H_1(U\cap V)$ is given by $\alpha \colon [0,1] \to U\cap V$ where $\alpha(t) = [\frac{1}{2} e^{2\pi i t}]$, and a generator of $H_1(S)$ (and hence $H_1(U)$) is given by $\gamma\colon [0,1] \to S\subset U$ where $\gamma(t) = [e^{\frac{2\pi}{3} i t}]$. But in $U$, $\alpha$ is homotopic to $\tilde{\alpha}(t) = [e^{2\pi i t}]$ and they represent the same homology class, and we can see that $\tilde{\alpha} \sim \gamma * \gamma * \gamma$ (where $*$ is concatenation of paths). Therefore the map $H_1(U\cap V) \to H_1(U)$ is multiplication by $3$ and we have

$$ H_0(X) \cong \mathbb{Z}, H_1(X) \cong \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}, \text{ and }H_n(X) =0 \text { otherwise.} $$

Comment: What happens if instead of having $\mathbb{D}^2$, we have $S^1$, that is, if the space is $X=S^1/\sim$ where $(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))\sim (\cos(\theta+\frac{2\pi}{3}),\sin(\theta+\frac{2\pi}{3}))$, in this case we could determine which space is homotopically equivalent $X$? Thank you.

Comment: The quotient of $S^1$ by this relation is homeomorphic to the "$S$" that I have in my answer, which is homeomorphic to $S^1$.

Comment: @Willian 
How can I calculate the homology groups of $X$, I have already calculated these for $n>2$, and I realized that $H_0(X)\cong \mathbb{Z}$ and $H_n(X)=0$ if $n>2$, but what can I do with $n=1,2$? 
I am using the succession of mayer vietoris to do this.

Comment: That's quite different from your original question. What have you tried so far? What are the two subspaces you are considering for the Mayer-Vietoris sequence?

Comment: @Willian I am considering $U=X-\{\overline{(0,0)}\}$ and $V=Im\{int(\mathbb{D^2})\}$, so, we are going to have that $U\simeq \mathbb{S}^1$, $U\cap V\simeq \mathbb{S}^1$ and $V$ is contractile, then $H_n(V)\cong 0$ if $n=0$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ otherwise. On the other hand $H_n(U)=H_n(U\cap V)\cong \mathbb{Z}$ if $n=0,1$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: That setup looks good to me. Now the piece of information you still need is the map $H_1(U\cap V) \to H_1(U)$. Both of these groups are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$, can you see what the homomorphism should be?

Comment: @Willian 
At this point is where I am confused, to know what the $H_1(U\cap V)\to H_1(U)$ function is, I have thought about taking geometric generators for $H_1(U\cap V)$ and $H_1(U)$ and see the generator of $H_1(U\cap V)$ where it is sent in $H_1(U)$. A generator of $H_1(U\cap V)$ would be a circle of radio less than one parameterized by $\alpha$, so $[|\alpha|]$ generates $H_1(U\cap V)$, but which element generates $H_1(U)$?

Comment: Note that U deformation retracts onto $Im\{ \partial D^2 \} = S$, and a generator of $H_1(S)$ (and hence $H_1(U)$) can be represented by $\gamma\colon [0,1] \to S$ where $\gamma(t) = [e^{\frac{2\pi}{3} i t}  ]$ (I'm switching to complex coordinates because they're more concise).The image of the circle $\alpha$ under $H_1(U\cap V) \to H_1(U) \cong H_1(S)$ is represented by $\tilde{\alpha}(t) = [e^{2\pi i t}]$. Can you see the relation between $\tilde{\alpha}$ and $\gamma$?

Comment: @Willian 
Yes, I can establish the connection and with what you just said I have managed to prove what I was missing: $ H_2(X) = 0 $ and $ H_1(X) = \mathbb {Z}_3$. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Willian I could calculate the homology groups of this space by calling $A=\text{
the points that are identified in this space}$ and using $...\to H_n(A)\to H_n(X)\to H(X,A)\to H_{n-1}(A)\to...$ is it 
exact?