# Identifying triple points of a disc's boundry

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, quotient-spaces

It is known that if we identify each pair of antipodal points on the edge of a 2-D disc, we'll have a real projective plane.

Now I'm curious about the structures which are emerged when we identify 3 or more symmetrical points on the edge.
(For example for 3 point case we merge each triple points of the circumference which are on 120 degree distant pairwise.)

What can we know about these structures? Are they manifolds?...

Comment: One can use van Kampen's theorem to show that $\pi_1(M_n) \cong \mathbb{Z}/n$ where $M_n$ is the space with points identified $n$ times as you've described above.

Comment: There is a related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3272277/let-x-mathbbd2-sim-where-cos-theta-sin-theta-sim-cos-theta-f). Geometrically you can describe such a space by attaching a disk to a circle by a degree $n$ map on the boundary. Contrary to @jdoicj's comment, it will *NOT* be a manifold unless $n = 1$ or $2$, because it will not be locally Euclidean along this circle.

Comment: @William That's great idea attaching the disc to a circle by degree $n$ map. Thanks.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1832450.